# passing multi params with URL on php

Tags: php, insert, insert-update

i have a .php for creating record in table. i think it's right but i can't pass parameters from URL to it and somethings wrong with that.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

i pass params in url like this:

```
localhost:81/android/create_product.php?name='test'&price='35000'&description='test'
```

is the php code is wrong or it's something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for URL paramiters

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['description']))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are passing parameters in url then you need to get it by

```
$_GET['name']
```

method not by $_POST['name'] like

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['description']))
```